# MIPS - I wrote a mips code that gives each line in the file a hexadecimal number I want to check the same word, give it the same hexadecimal

Tags: mips

```
.data
fin: .asciiz "input.txt"
buffer: .space 1
line: .space 1024
line_counter: .word 1  # initialize line counter to 1
com: .asciiz " "

result: .space 8

.globl main
.text
main:
    la $s1,buffer
    la $s2,line
    li $s3,0      # current line length

    # open file
    li $v0, 13    # syscall for open file
    la $a0, fin   # input file name
    li $a1, 0     # read flag
    li $a2, 0     # ignore mode 
    syscall       # open file 
    move $s0, $v0 # save the file descriptor 

read_loop:
    # read byte from file
    li $v0, 14    # syscall for read file
    move $a0, $s0 # file descriptor 
    move $a1, $s1 # address of dest buffer
    li $a2, 1     # buffer length
    syscall       # read byte from file

    # keep reading until bytes read <= 0
    blez $v0, read_done

    # naively handle exceeding line size by exiting
    slti $t0, $s3, 1024
    beqz $t0, read_done

    # if current byte is a newline, consume line
    lb $s4, ($s1)
    li $t0, 10
    beq $s4, $t0, consume_line

    # otherwise, append byte to line
    add $s5, $s3, $s2
    sb $s4, ($s5)

    # increment line length
    addi $s3, $s3, 1

    b read_loop

consume_line:
    # null terminate line
    add $s5, $s3, $s2
    sb $zero, ($s5)

    # reset bytes read
    li $s3, 0

    # convert line counter to hexadecimal string using itoa system call
    li $v0, 34          # syscall for itoa
    lw $a0, line_counter # load line counter
    la $a1, result     # load address of result string
    li $a2, 16         # specify base 16 (hexadecimal)
    syscall            # convert line counter to hexadecimal string

    # Print the hexadecimal number
    li $v0, 4       # syscall for printing string
    la $a0, result  # load the address of the result string
    syscall

    # increment line counter
    lw $t0, line_counter
    addi $t0, $t0, 1
    sw $t0, line_counter
    
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, com
    syscall 

    # print line (or consume it some other way)
    move $a0, $s2
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    # print newline
    li $a0, 10
    li $v0, 11
    syscall

    b read_loop

read_done:
    # close file
    li $v0, 16     # syscall for close file
    move $a0, $s0  # file descriptor to close
    syscall       # close file
    

    # exit the program
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

I've tried that, but I'm having the same problem when switching to a new line

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking.  Are you looking for an algorithm?  If so, suggest to work it out in C as there's no need to craft an algorithm directly in assembly.  Do you need to debug it?  If so, use the single step feature and compare with your working algorithm.

Comment: This code assigns a hexadecimal number to each line, but I want it to give the same hexadecimal number for the contents of similar lines

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for an algorithm.  That starts with a clear definition of what you're trying to do.  You'll need to define what you mean by "similar lines", for example.  And to be clear you can work out an algorithm in any language as they all can manipulate bytes and numbers; suggest doing so in a language you know well, then bring the algorithm to MIPS assembly line by line and expression by expression.